# Can a cyanotype be used for long exposure photography?

Tags: film

I wanted to make a home-made camera, and I was trying to find some type of film or paper that wasn't hard to develop or handle.

So, I thought about using a cyanotype because of how common it is and its long exposure time. My only issue is that I don't know if this is an effective way to do this. I would only be able to take still shots, and I don't know if I will end up with a blurry smudge for a photo due to the exposure time.

For technical specs, I am just going to use a cardboard box with a pinhole. I'm not a photographer, so I am just unsure.

Comment: I can't remember what chemicals she used - but Linda McCartney wrote a book about her experiments in this field, which you may find interesting - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sun-Prints-Linda-McCartney/dp/0821227378

Comment: Prepare yourself for loooong exposure times. Using photographic sheet film (read very light sensitive) required many minutes of exposure time with a pinhole lens. You won't need a stopwatch. You will need something to hold the camera from moving during the hour or two exposure time. ; )

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the exposures would be extremely long. Consider using ordinary silver halide (darkroom) photographic paper. They should be readily available. You will need a dark room and ideally a safe light, but overall I think the manipulation and processing will be easier, especially with resin coated papers.